# USB 3 port fails to enable my keyboard during boot

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot, keyboard, power

My laptop has both USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports. I've connected:

- mouse -- USB 2.0 port
- keyboard -- USB 3.0 port

On starting the system, the mouse is active however the keyboard does not function. Everytime i have to disconnect the keyboard and plug it back in and only then it becomes active.

Is there any fix to this problem or is the USB port itself faulty?

specs: Dell XPS, 64-bit i7 processor with 8G of RAM

Comment: What operating system? Do you dual-boot? Do you have a liveCD or live USB drive available to boot into?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit. No dual boot, just the one OS. I'm not sure about liveCD, how would it help?

Comment: It would really only help in the Linux realm. Log files and differing Linux distros could reveal a lot to see what's going on. But not really for Windows.

Comment: Does it work (without reconnecting) before you boot into an OS? In other words, can you use it on the startup/BIOS screen? Does the mouse or the keyboard exhibit the same problem if you swap the ports?

Comment: @Bob No it doesn't work on the BIOS screen as well. I also tried connecting both the mouse and keyboard to a USB hub and then the hub to the port - both keyboard and mouse stop working. :(

Comment: @Bob Also, the keyboard works fine when connected to the USB 2.0 port. Tried connecting an external HDD to the USB 3.0 port - It does not detect in the system. Once i disconnect and plug it back in again, it shows up.